# Contatenation of Path Stored in a Variable

Tags: asp.net

.Write( "" & ProductImage  & "" & vbcrlf )

ProductImage=/senful/65319.jpg

the first code displays path stored in the ProductImage but what I intend to do is to write the image by concatenating the src property value(source path in the second code) with ProductImage to display the image in my table. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$"<td style=\"text-align: left;\">< img border = 0 title = \"Product Active\" src =\"/web_utils/images/\"{ProductImage}></td>"
```

Or like this with UriBuilder:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("stackoverflow.com:3333");
var td = $"<td style=\"text-align: left;\">< img border = 0 title = \"Product Active\" src =\"{uriBuilder.ToString()}\"></td>";
```

Or if the variable contains the full html then you need a Html Parser to call(if you don't want to do with regex):

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument(); 
string htmlString = "<html>blabla</html>";
document.LoadHtml(htmlString);
HtmlNodeCollection collection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
foreach (HtmlNode link in collection)
{
     string target = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to asp.net and I am just editing the code and generating the result dynamically. Could you please just edit my submitted code. Thank you.